# Using MSBuild to deploy an ASP.NET website project

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have an ASP.NET website project (the ones without a .csproj file) and I want to have it deployed to an IIS server using web deploy, but the msbuild task only runs a build and does not deploy it.

For the website I made a .msbuild file which is used in the msbuild command to build the project.

I have a similar setup for a web application project that uses a .csproj file and it does the deployment fine, so I want to know what I am missing for the website.

Both projects have publish profiles (.pubxml) which is where the deployment info gets saved.

The msbuild commands being triggered looks like this:

Web Application
`msbuild -r WepApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True`

Website
`msbuild -r WepSite.msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True`

So they are identical, except for the fact that the application references the .csproj file, while the website references the .msbuild file

The msbuild file's contents are as follows:

```
<Project
        xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
        DefaultTargets = "PrecompileWeb">
        <Target Name = "PrecompileWeb">
                <AspNetCompiler
                        VirtualPath="/"  
                        PhysicalPath=".\"  
                        TargetPath=".\Built" 
                        Force = "true"
                        Debug = "true"/>
        </Target>
</Project>
```

I used [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/aspnetcompiler-task?view=vs-2022) as a reference on making the .msbuild file, but I do not see any parameters related to publishing withing the AspNetCompiler task.

These builds and deployments are triggered via a workflow on a build server, and the IIS server is separate, so I cannot make use of the msbuild Copy task since the build server cannot access the storage of the IIS server.

Any ideas on if and/or how this can be achieved would be much appreciated.

Comment: The AspNetCompiler task doesn't perform deployments. The task is described as follows: "The AspNetCompiler task wraps aspnet_compiler.exe, a utility to precompile ASP.NET applications." That is not deployment. The .csproj project file is importing in a set of support files that include the publish logic. Your .msbuild file doesn't have any of that. I did a quick google on .pubxml and everything I found assumes a true project file. You also mention Web Deploy which is different and, I believe, doesn't use .pubxml files.

Comment: @JonathanDodds yeah I saw that the AspNetCompiler task doesn't deploy, and was hoping to find out if there is another task type that perhaps solves that problem. Also, the pubxml files are publish profiles for .Net projects, which can be set up to deploy in n number of different ways, including FTP, Filesystem, Azure, and web deploy.

Comment: Yes, pubxml files are publish profiles. `msdeploy.exe` doesn't appear to use or accept .pubxml files. But the Visual Studio IDE publish wizard and Legacy style and SDK style MSBuild projects do use .pubxml files.